# Can't find spring-context Schema from WildFly 10 Module

Tags: java, spring, jboss, wildfly

I've been searching and fighting this all day and nothing I have found has been able to resolve this issue. I am in the progress of attempting to migrate a spring-based application to WildFly 10 (from a legacy JBoss application server) and am having issues when deploying.

For this application, I have my application (MyApplication.war) and 2 modules, Spring 3.1.2 and MyCustomJar.jar. The custom JAR contains spring XML configuration files (and is what appears to be blowing up on WildFly).

The WAR file deploys, and the spring container gets initialized. However once it starts to try and process bean definitions from mycustomjar.jar!myspring-app.xml it errors out because it cannot find the spring context schema. The stack trace from wildfly and my module + jboss-deployment-structure are included. Any ideas to try would be appreciated. I have done about every variation of import/export from the spring module that I could find online today with absolutely no effect.

```
2017-03-02 14:58:08,282 INFO  [org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Thu Mar 02 14:58:08 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-03-02 14:58:08,317 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Loading XML bean definitions from URL [jar:file:/c:/data/apps/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/mycustomjar/mycustomjar.jar!/myspring-context.xml]
2017-03-02 14:58:08,518 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [myspring-app.xml]
2017-03-02 14:58:08,575 INFO  [org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [myspring-services.xml]
2017-03-02 14:58:08,676 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 62) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Failed to import bean definitions from URL location [classpath:myspring-services.xml]
Offending resource: URL [jar:file:/c:/data/apps/wildfly-10.1.0.Final/modules/mycustomjar/mycustomjar.jar!/myspring-context.xml]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/context]
Offending resource: class path resource [myspring-services.xml]
```

**org.springframework.spring**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.3" name="org.springframework.spring" slot="3.1.2">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.aop-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.asm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.aspects-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.beans-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.context-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.context.support-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.core-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.expression-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.instrument-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.jms-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.oxm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.test-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.transaction-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.web-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
        <resource-root path="org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api" export="true" />
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
        <module name="org.apache.commons.logging" />
        <module name="org.jboss.vfs" />
        <module name="org.jboss.msc" />
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

**MyCustomJar.jar**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="mycustomjar">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mycustomjar.jar" />
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

**MyApplication.war jboss-deployment-structure.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure xmlns="urn:jboss:deployment-structure:1.2">
    <deployment>
        <dependencies>
            <module name="javax.servlet.api" />
            <module name="org.springframework.spring" meta-inf="export" export="true" />
            <module name="mycustomjar" />
        </dependencies>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

**EDIT**
I started testing around with different spring versions, and upgrading to 3.2.14 I was able to get it running without any issues using the above configuration. Are the schema files located in a different spot in 3.1.2? It has to be something with those specific versions because a simple upgrade fixed everything